# Running Serverless Framework CLI commands, like "deploy", from Maven

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

What I am trying to do:

1. Build the (AWS Lambda function) Java Maven module, with the `mvn` command and goals, as usual.
2. Depending on given custom goals, Maven will call Serverless CLI commands to deploy the Java based Lambda function, using the serverless.yml file in the root dir of the module.
3. Maven continues with end to end test, using URLs returned by Serverless CLI command call (`deploy`). Or by sending messages to a queue, if that's the event triggering the function.

So, I've been searching for a Maven plugin for Serverless Framework CLI, but I can't find anyone. I really want Maven to execute the Serverless CLI when certain goals are given.

This is what I think my options might be, right now:

- Write the Maven plugin myself.
- Use shell scripts, I consider it ugly, but thats subjective.
- Get a tip of a Maven plugin I've missed.
- Another slick way to accomplish what I want, that I'm unaware of.

I appreciate all ideas, but really I'm focusing to solve this within the Maven lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

> Another slick way to accomplish what I want, that I'm unaware of

I think a way the achieve this is to add the scripts to a step in your build server.  Maven's primary function is to act as a build manager which is slightly different from the deployment use case you are outlining above.

Comment: I both agree and disagree, Maven even have a deploy phase for pushing artifacts to a central repository. But yes, we do not use that, we use Jenkins Pipelines to take care of that, with maven deploy executions.

However, writing small AWS Lambda functions, opens up for developers to deploy them from their laptops (for testing) with their own tags, so they are accessable through "http://developername.company.com/service/user/23", after say "mvn test serverless:deploy -Dstack=developername". I want this to happen within a maven phase.

Comment: For full disclosure, I found this page because I was looking for this exact thing.  However, the your comment of "Get a tip of a Maven plugin I've missed" I've taken to be a clue that there is probably a more correct way to solve this problem.  You could extend the Maven lifecycle to run additional tests after assembly of the jar but this breaks the Maven lifecycle.  I think pragmatically you would want to put most of your testing in the unit testing layer and then just trust the Serverless deployment.

Comment: True. But, artifacts are built before the verify phase, so within that phase I would like to, optionally, push the contents up using serverless for end-2-end tests, using maven. When maven lifecycle was designed, little was known about serverless architecture, and how easy you can fully end-2-end test it with automation, but we can't let that stop us.

So right now, it looks like we have to 1. Write our own plugins, 2. Ditch maven or 3. Do it manually, meaning the devs, probably by writing shell scrtips for it. 1 and 2 is okay, but cumbersome. 3 is not an option.

Comment: I'm also here because I'm thinking this would be a nice thing to do. One option would be to use the http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ plugin and configure calls out to the system's serverless (sls) command at the appropriate Maven lifecycle stage. You could use variables in the pom (which could be overridden by the developer) to configure what gets called by exec (for instance, doing a deploy for a particular developer, like you mention). For post-run integration tests you'd probably have to parse the exec plugin's output (at which point maybe writing your own plugin is easier).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still intrigued by this I've started an inspired effort at https://github.com/olensmar/serverless4j/tree/master/maven-plugin - still working on how this would optimally fit in the maven lifecycle - ideas/suggestions as always welcome!